# opening html file in j2me application

Tags: html, netbeans, java-me

how can open html files(local files) in j2me application?

Answer (score 0):

You can access to file from a URL: use HttpConnection then open a
stream and read from it.

You can access data from the .JAD which comes with the MIDlet (or the
MANIFEST.MF file if no .JAD): use MIDlet.getAppProperty(String).

You can access database through the rms package of MIDP. Note that you
will access only database that your MIDlet create (or other MIDlet
created with the shared flag set to true).

You can't access any file from the phone (for ex., in Symbian OS, you
can't open a file by URL: "file://C/System/file.ext").

Comment: local files means files in j2me package(jar file)